Suggested preconditioners for Broydens method?
thanks for reading my post.
I am currently using Broydens method to solve a system of nonlinear equations.  I identify the initial Jacobian numerically, and then use the Broyden update to identify subsequent Jacobians.
I'd like to reduce the number of iterations per time step, and have sought out a preconditioner.  I'm totally new to this field and there are tons of options out there, but most either seem unapplicable to my problem (my Jacobian matrix is not symmetric) or they are expensive to implement.
Appreciate any tips, guidance etc.
For context, I am a mechanical engineer working in flight simulation.  I don't have a deep background in numerical linear algebra.  Trying to get pointed in the right direction.  Thanks!

can you make your problem a little more detailed, since there are many ways to precondition the matrix.

Please give a good reference to the "Broydens method" (I had never heard of it).

Why don't you answer my little question ?
